# Auxiliary class - define in companion object or as inner class

Tags: scala

Is there an **(dis)advantage** (for example performance-wise) for defining classes auxiliary to a trait in its **companion object** over defining them as **inner classes**? For example:

```
object Foo {
  final class Bar[A, B](val x: A, val y: B)
}
trait Foo[A, B] {
  def foo: Foo.Bar[A, B]
}
```

vs.

```
trait Foo[A, B] {
  final class Bar(val x: A, val y: B)
  def foo: Bar
}
```

I tend to use the first variant—because it does not require access to any member of `Foo`—but since the type parameters become redundant, I'm thinking about switching to the second variant. Class `Bar` is only used internally, so could get a `protected` modifier.

I reckon the internal class with have an invisible `Foo.this` member somewhere, but then my understanding is that `Foo.Bar` is also not purely static as in Java but probably has some pointer to `Foo$.this`, too.

Comment: In the second version, I think you mean `def foo: Bar` ?